# iOS collectionview reloaddata invalidatelayout

Tags: ios, xamarin, layout, collectionview

I have a problem with my collectionView. This is what I want to do and what I have at the moment:

- 1 collectionView
- 1 datasource
- 2 layout
- 2 prototyp cells

I got 2 buttons to switch between layout and prototypes cells

Can someone tell me **how many times** et **when** I have to use these methods (constructor? method when I click on a button ? subviewLayout method ?)

```
collectionViewTransactions.CollectionViewLayout = new CollectionViewLayoutGrid();

collectionViewTransactions.CollectionViewLayout = new CollectionViewLayoutList();

collectionViewTransactions.Source = new TransactionCollectionViewSource();

collectionViewTransactions.ReloadData();

collectionViewTransactions.CollectionViewLayout.InvalidateLayout();
```

Because I got 9 items and the first time, it displays only 4 (which appears on screen), How can also display all 9 instead of only which are display on screen ?

Please can someone help me, thank a lot !

Comment: The second line overwrites the first: replacing grid with list. Is that a typo?

Comment: It's not my final code. It's just line, I just want to know where I have to use them because when I switch of layout the first time , it works, but the second time no, 

I got the impression , cells are replaced by others

Answer (score 0):

Be careful not to confuse the layout object’s **invalidateLayout** method with the collection view’s **reloadData** method. Calling the **invalidateLayout** method does not necessarily cause the collection view to throw out its existing cells and subviews. Rather, it forces the layout object to recompute all of its layout attributes as is necessary when moving and adding or deleting items. If data within the data source has changed, the **reloadData** method is appropriate. Regardless of how you initiate a layout update, the actual layout process is the same.